# Rest API with mix of Path Param and RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have been asked to build a Rest endpoint that is a mix of path param and request param, looks like -

```
/user/{user}?refresh={refresh}
```

The request param should be optional.

I have tried `String getUser(@PathVariable String user, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params);` but it makes the RequestParam mandatory (as it shows in Swagger UI).

How can I make it optional ?

Comment: Btw., `refresh` is called a query parameter - what Spring calls a "request parameter" is just a wrapper for multiple types of parameters (form, query, ...)

Comment: @Smutje I didn't see a @ QueryParam annotation. Is there another way to annotate query parameter type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`required`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#required--) to `false` in the [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation, as follows:

```java
@GetMapping("/user/{user}?refresh={refresh}")
String getUser(@PathVariable String user, @RequestParam(required = false) String refresh) {
    ...
}
```